# delete certain redirect using rules

Tags: rules, redirection

Can anybody suggest an idea how to delete redirect using rules? I have found a rules patch that allows editing redirects. https://www.drupal.org/node/1653542 but not deleting it.
Usercase: When working on an article while it is unpublished, drupal creates redirects as well. I would like to delete all redirects upon publishing a node.

Comment: By deleting such redirects, you wouldn't be redirected of course. But what would then be the actual URL to be shown instead for such unplublished article? Just something like "node/node-id"? Can you provide an example of it?

Comment: HI, until article is unpublished - drupal can create redirects as many as necessary. But after I publish the node, I need to delete all redirects and use only the last one.